# Unwanted border-radius corners around images in Brave/Chrome browser

Tags: html, css

I tried to display a simple image, inside of a container with `border-radius: 5px;`. But there seem to be an outline of thin border at the corners (you'll need to look carefully at the below image). How can I avoid these corner borders ?

[image]

```css
.cover {
    margin: 1em;
    padding: 1em;
}
.image-wrapper {
    height: 15em;
    width: 15em;
    overflow: hidden;
    background-color: black;
    border-radius: 15px;
}
img {
    height: 100%;
    width: auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="cover">
    <div class="image-wrapper">
        <img
            src="https://images.pexels.com/photos/316466/pexels-photo-316466.jpeg"
        />
    </div>
</div>
```

Yes, it goes away if I remove `background-color: black;`. But I need to retain the `background-color` and I also need `img { height: 100%; width: auto; }` to maintain the aspect ratio and to care of scenarios when the size of the image is too thin or too wide, etc.

Searching for other similar questions, I could only find questions/responses for Safari. I'm using Brave browser.

Comment: Does adding `border-color: transparent` on .image-wrapper make that go away?

Comment: Yep it does. It seems to be a Chrome bug. If you toggle the radius on/off from devtools it fixes it. Weird.

Comment: @Miro sadly border color transparent does not cure the problem. What may have happened is that if you try things in say dev tools things get shifted slightly and the 'left over' pixels disappear. Putting border-color: transparent into the actual snippet and running it, the unwanted dots are there (on some zoom levels).

Comment: Sorry I misread. I tried with `background:none; ` or transparent and it works.

Comment: It seems to be to do with how the system deals with the fact that on many modern devices one CSS pixel maps to several physical screen pixels, and particularly when rounding corners, some screen pixels get ‘left behind’, depending on the calculation used for mapping an arc to  screen pixels. The answer from @temaniafif is the only suggestion so far here that works (others rely on things changing e.g. because of using dev tools and subsequent zooming).

Comment: Also Firefox does it too. It may not be webkit at fault.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Using mask instead of overflow gives a better result (both behave the same since both *hide* what is outside)

```css
.cover {
  margin: 1em;
  padding: 1em;
}

.image-wrapper {
  height: 15em;
  width: 15em;
  background-color: black;
  border-radius: 15px;
  -webkit-mask:linear-gradient(#fff 0 0);
}

img {
  height: 100%;
  width: auto;
}

body {
  background:pink;
}
```

```html
<div class="cover">
  <div class="image-wrapper">
    <img src="https://images.pexels.com/photos/316466/pexels-photo-316466.jpeg" />
  </div>
</div>

<div class="cover">
  <div class="image-wrapper">
    <img src="https://picsum.photos/id/17/200/300" />
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: @KayaToast you can keep it open forever ;) you aren't obliged to accpet fast or to accept at all.

Answer (score 0):

Pretty sure this is a webkit bug since turning `borer-radius` off and back on from devtool fixed it. <s>A possible work-around would be to not use wrapper and add `object-fit:cover` to the image to make it responsive. You can also try `object-fit:contain` but that will produce black banding.</s> You can send a Chrome bug report from `Help>Report an Issue` if you feel like it.

Edit: Never mind. Apparently it fixes itself if you scroll up and down the page a few times and I thought it worked.

```css
.cover {
    margin: 1em;
    padding: 1em;
}

img {
    border-radius: 15px;
    height: 100%;
    width: auto;
    height: 15em;
    width: 15em;
    overflow: hidden;
    background-color: black;
    border-radius: 15px;
    object-fit:cover;
}
```

```html
<div class="cover">
    <div class="image-wrapper">
        <img
            src="https://images.pexels.com/photos/316466/pexels-photo-316466.jpeg"
        />
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

This hack seems to work.

```
background-clip: content-box;
padding: 1px;
```

`background-clip: content-box;` has better browser support than `-webkit-mask`

```css
.cover {
    margin: 1em;
    padding: 1em;
}
.image-wrapper {
    height: 15em;
    width: 15em;
    overflow: hidden;
    background-color: black;
    border-radius: 15px;
    background-clip: content-box;
    padding: 1px;
}
img {
    height: 100%;
    width: auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="cover">
    <div class="image-wrapper">
        <img src="https://images.pexels.com/photos/316466/pexels-photo-316466.jpeg" alt="hello" />
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: simply pay attention to the extra pixel added as it may give you some unwanted whitespaces.

Comment: agreed, it is a tradeoff. `-webkit-mask` does not have universal support, and in the alternate approach, the extra whitespaces for padding can be undesirable.

Answer (score -2):

It could be because of the `background-color: black;`. Try to remove it, and if it's not working add a `border: none;`

Comment: Neither of these things will work. The question specifically says the black background is required and border: none does not work.

Answer (score -4):

I guess its might be your image, went through the same format on my laptop, my image was never providing the rounded border corner,  though add border: none; to your code and see the result

Comment: The image does not have a border. You can see it by copy/pasting the image source in your browser address bar.