# Why is the border funky when a radius is applied?

Tags: html, css, sass, frontend

I was messing around in HTML when I saw this small bug

I made this button using SCSS and gave it a border radius of `5px`. If you're able to notice, there's a small curve where the border raidus is supposed to be.

[image: Button]

Close up:

[image: Zoomed in version]

Why is this happening?

#### Code

```css
/* Button.scss file */

@import "../../util/variables";

button {
    background-color: white;
    color: black;
    outline: none;
    border: 1px currentColor solid;
    padding: 0.3rem 0.85rem;
    border-radius: $border-radius;

    &:hover {
        cursor: pointer;
    }

    &.primary {
        background-color: $primary;
        color: $primary-text;
    }

    &.secondary {
        background-color: $secondary;
        color: $secondary-text;
    }

    &.block {
        display: block;
        width: 100%;
        margin-bottom: 0.5rem;
    }
}
```

```html
<!-- HTML -->

<button
    class="button"
>
    Login
</button>
```

EDIT:

- `$primary` is `#283593`
- I use firefox

```css
button {
     background-color: white;
     color: black;
     outline: none;
     border: 1px currentColor solid;
     padding: 0.3rem 0.85rem;
     border-radius: 5px;
}
 button:hover {
     cursor: pointer;
}
 button.primary {
     background-color: #283593;
     color: white;
}
 button.block {
     display: block;
     width: 100%;
     margin-bottom: 0.5rem;
}
```

```html
<button class="button primary">Login</button>
```

Comment: This could be dependent on the rendering engine. Which browser do you use?

Comment: Firefox browser, and I'm using the svelte framework with SASS

Comment: I made you a snippet. Is it correct after applying your variables?

Comment: related: https://stackoverflow.com/q/66288711/8620333

Comment: Looks perfectly nice in Brave Browser v1.21.77

Comment: @mplungjan nope, still the same error

Comment: Is the SNIPPET correct, I.e. what you have WITH the variables

Comment: I copy-pasted the thing exactly

Answer (score 0):

This is an artifact caused by the imprecision of fractional numbers used in the rendering.  You can expect it to vary depending on browser, and perhaps even GPU and rendering mode.

See also:  [Is floating point math broken?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/588004/362536)