# CSS overflow hidden has a glitch causing whitespace next to border

Tags: html, css, overflow, border

I have here very simple code that shows a glitch in which there is a bit of white space where there shouldnt be, in the corner of the border radius. I simply have a colored div behined a button with overflow hidden.
In chrome it's very bad when you zoom in and out you can see a lot of whitespace in the whole border where the overflow hidden is active.
[[click to see chrome screenshot]](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XQ8Qy.png)
In firefox it is better but there is still white space in the corner where there shouldnt be.
[[click to see firefox screenshot]](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HNwxl.png)
I couldn't figure out any fixes around this and it is very ugly, pls help! thx

```html
<style>
    button {
        border: 10px solid purple;
        border-radius: 30px;
        height:300px;
        width:300px;
        overflow: hidden;
        position: relative;
    }
    div {
        background: purple;
        position: absolute;
        height: 400px;
        width: 400px;
    }
</style>
<body>
        <button><div></div></button>
</body>
```

Comment: div can not be in button tag ... https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15885444/why-cant-a-button-element-contain-a-div#:~:text=We%20decided%20to%20throw%20our,inside%20a%20tag.&text=Results%20in%3A,further%20errors%20from%20this%20subtree.)

Comment: related: https://stackoverflow.com/a/66289575/8620333

Answer (score 0):

You can use css `linear-gradient` to solve this:

```css
button {
  border: 10px solid purple;
  border-radius: 30px;
  height: 300px;
  width: 300px;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
  background: linear-gradient(transparent 100px, purple 100px);
}
```

```html
<button></button>
```

Comment: It's a good alternative for this specific code but I am originally trying to make one of those sliding backgrounds on hover for buttons, and my ::before element is a div and a linear background cant replace it i dont think

Comment: https://codepen.io/tamircode/pen/VwPBEvN?editors=1100 here is the code for my button with ::before issue